# custom setjmp/longjmp implemetation segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, setjmp

I'm trying to implement custom **setjmp/longjmp** for x64 windows.
I have following code:

```
contextSave:
xorq %rdx,%rdx  
movq %rdx,(%rcx)  
movq %rbx,0x8(%rcx)  
leaq 0x8(%rsp),%rax  
movq %rax,0x10(%rcx)  
movq %rbp,0x18(%rcx)  
movq %rsi,0x20(%rcx)  
movq %rdi,0x28(%rcx)  
movq %r12,0x30(%rcx)  
movq %r13,0x38(%rcx)    
movq %r14,0x40(%rcx)   
movq %r15,0x48(%rcx)  
movq (%rsp),%rax  
movq %rax,0x50(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm6,0x60(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm7,0x70(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm8,0x80(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm9,0x90(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm10,0xa0(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm11,0xb0(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm12,0xc0(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm13,0xd0(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm14,0xe0(%rcx)  
movdqa %xmm15,0xf0(%rcx)  
xorq %rax,%rax  
retq   
contextRestore:  
movq $1,%rax  
movq 0x8(%rcx),%rbx  
movq 0x18(%rcx),%rbp  
movq 0x20(%rcx),%rsi  
movq 0x28(%rcx),%rdi  
movq 0x30(%rcx),%r12  
movq 0x38(%rcx),%r13  
movq 0x40(%rcx),%r14  
movq 0x48(%rcx),%r15  
movdqa 0x60(%rcx),%xmm6  
movdqa 0x70(%rcx),%xmm7  
movdqa 0x80(%rcx),%xmm8  
movdqa 0x90(%rcx),%xmm9  
movdqa 0xa0(%rcx),%xmm10  
movdqa 0xb0(%rcx),%xmm11  
movdqa 0xc0(%rcx),%xmm12  
movdqa 0xd0(%rcx),%xmm13  
movdqa 0xe0(%rcx),%xmm14  
movdqa 0xf0(%rcx),%xmm15  
movq 0x50(%rcx),%rdx    
movq 0x10(%rcx),%rsp  
jmp *%rdx
```

Execution context is saved in following structs:

```
typedef struct Float128{
   unsigned long part[2];
  }Float128 __attribute__((aligned(16)));
  typedef struct ContextData{
   long frame;
   long rbx;
   long rsp;
   long rbp;
   long rsi;
   long rdi;
   long r12;
   long r13;
   long r14;
   long r15;
   long rip;
   long spare;
   Float128 Xmm6;
   Float128 Xmm7;
   Float128 Xmm8;
   Float128 Xmm9;
   Float128 Xmm10;
   Float128 Xmm11;
   Float128 Xmm12;
   Float128 Xmm13;
   Float128 Xmm14;
   Float128 Xmm15;
   }ContextData;
```

Code is modified version of [this](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/misc/setjmp.S),[this](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/misc/longjmp.S) and [this](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/setjmp.h)

**gdb** shows the following error message:

> #0  0x000000000040231e in contextRestore ()   Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d

Info registers shows that **0xbaadf00dbaadf00d** is stored in many registers. **contextSave** is not working as expected.
Update:
It seems that the problem is outside of showed code. I created a simple code with the functions to isolate the problem. It is causing a following error.

> Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Registers seem to be ok thought.

```
ContextData context;
if(contextSave(context)==1){
 puts("context restored");
 exit(0);
}
contextRestore(context);
```

Update 2
Debugging shows that rsp,rpb and rip are zero in ContextData struct.
So they are not save properly by contextSave.

Comment: Are you running on Linux or Windows? This code is using the Windows calling convention.

Comment: windows i wil add that to question

Comment: The code you’ve shown here looks fine, so probably the problem is in the code you haven’t shown. Can you write a minimal test program that exhibits the problem. (My guess is that a minimal test case will work.)

Comment: I used the functions in different code, but it caused corrupt stack error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seem that the structs were the problem. I don´t whatever the functions are correctly
implemnted. I have decided to only use the structs and use standart library for now.

Correct types:

```
typedef struct Float128{
   unsigned long long data[2]
}Float128 __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef Float128 Context[16];
```